# ¿Por qué mi código no toma mi isNaN()?

Tags: javascript

Básicamente la idea es que el programa verifique mediante el `isNaN()` que el valor ingresado sea un número, y que sea mayor o igual a 0.

```js
var defectuoso1;
defectuoso1 = Number(prompt('Ingrese los productos defectuosos de la maquina 1',''));

while(isNaN(defectuoso1) && (defectuoso1 >= 0))
{
  defectuoso1 = Number(prompt('Ingrese un valor valido',''));
}
```

Sin embargo, al poner cualquier valor me lo toma como valido, cuando solo debería tomar como validos números mayores o iguales a cero.

Comment: No puede ser _NaN_ y mayor o igual que cero al mismo tiempo.

Answer (score 6):

Estás usando mal la función NaN, mira los siguientes ejemplos:

```js
console.log(isNaN(3));
console.log(isNaN('3A'));
```

La primera nos da false debido a que 3 si es un número, mientras que la segunda nos da true por que no es un número y si un string.

Entonces considera esto:

- Asumamos que la variable `defectuoso1` vale lo siguiente:

  ```
  defectuoso1 = 10;
  ```
- Entonces dentro de tu while con estas 2 condiciones:

  ```
  isNaN(defectuoso1) && (defectuoso1 >= 0)
  ```

La función da false y la comparación da true, esto genera que una de las condiciones no se cumplan y considerando que estás usando el operador `AND`este requiere que las condiciones de los extremos sean ambas ciertas.

Revisa esto:

```js
    let defectuoso1 = Number(prompt('Teclea un valor'));
    
    while (!isNaN(defectuoso1) && defectuoso1 >= 0) {
      console.log('Valor válido');
      break;
    }
```

**Referencias**

- [Objeto Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number)
- [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/isNaN)

Comment: Se debería leer sobre [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/isNaN) esta recomendado por sobre el uso de `isNaN()`

Answer (score 1):

yo lo haría de la siguiente manera:

```
var defectuoso1;
defectuoso1 = Number(prompt('Ingrese los productos defectuosos de la maquina 1',''));
while(defectuoso1 != NaN && defectuoso1 >= 0)
{
    defectuoso1 = Number(prompt('Ingrese un valor valido',''));
}
```

Comment: Para complementar tu respuesta, podrías agregar una explicación de que estaba mal. También mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Esta solucion lleva **[If Statements](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)**

```js
var defectuoso1;
defectuoso1 = Number(prompt('Ingrese los productos defectuosos de la maquina 1',''));

if(isNaN(defectuoso1)){
 defectuoso1 = Number(prompt('Ingrese un valor valido',''));
} else if (defectuoso1 <= 0 )
{
  defectuoso1 = Number(prompt('Ingrese un valor valido',''));
} else{
alert('numero valido')
}
```

Esta lleva [**bucle**:](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucle_while)

```js
var defectuoso1; //Declaramos la variables
    defectuoso1 = Number(prompt('Ingrese los productos defectuosos de la maquina 1','')); //Hacemos que el usuario nos pase un primer valor

    while(defectuoso1 < 0 || !Number(defectuoso1) ) //Si ese valor es menor a 0 o no es un numero
    {
        defectuoso1 = Number(prompt('Ingrese un valor valido','')); //Hacer que el usuario ponga de vuelta el numero
    }
```

Comment: Por lo pronto probe este cambio, me pide que sea un numero pero cuando pongo algo que no sea un numero en la confirmación el programa sigue incluso sin poner un numero

Comment: Cheque que ya cambié el código, espero te sirva :) y si es así, acuerdate de votarla para arriba y ponerla como respuesta más útil

Comment: Sigo con el mismo problema, y probe los 2 comandos, pero por lo visto sigue comprobando el valor en el primer prompt, pero en el siguiente donde deberia ir el valido si pongo algo invalido el programa continua.

Comment: @Vencho Para complementar tu respuesta, podrías agregar una explicación de que estaba mal. También mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ya lo agrego Gabito :)

Comment: @NicoL entonces te estas explicando mal porque este programa si funciona en base a lo que puedo entender en tu pregunta  :)

Comment: @Vencho, por lógica, tu opción con ciclo es la respuesta correcta, pero vendría bien que expliques porqué funciona y el código de la pregunta no.